# Function that query first element in a list of tuples and returns the other two

Tags: haskell

I would like to have list of tuples [(a,b,c)..] where a is String, b and c are Num. I will have a function, possibly pattern matching comprehension, that will only search for the first element (Unique ID) in any of the tuples in the list and if a match is found, the function will return remaining two elements in the tuple.

I'm new to programming and after much research I thought I would start with Haskell. I'm finding this http://learnyouahaskell.com very useful to start with but stuck at how comprehension and type annotations plays a role in pattern matching. So far what I see consistent in comprehension syntactically is that

```
{ Manipulate Set B, but mind the predicate | Trim it down further to make Set B | Select set A, Predicate }
```

I may sound naive and lazy, but honestly looking for some quick aha breakthrough so I can move on. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I might be wrong, because I don't know the full description of the problem, but I get the feeling you are using the wrong data structures here.  `Data.Map` is usually a better choice for holding objects pointed to by unique keys.  Also, custom data types are often a better choice than generic tuples.

Answer (score 2):

First, here's how you can pattern match inside list comprehensions:

```
[(b,c) | (a,b,c) <- input]
-- (b,c) constructs your results
-- (a,b,c) is the pattern matching
```

Then, just add your predicate:

```
[(b,c) | (a,b,c) <- input, a == id]
```

And, since these ids are unique, you're only interested in the first match, so just `take 1` from the above result.

---

Personally, I like `do` notation better:

```
do (a,b,c) <- input
   guard (a == id)
   return (b,c)
```

Comment: Thanks! I really see it now when you said "construct your result" vs manipulation. Both may sound the same but one is strict and other is loose when it comes to how you think about it. Neat one with guard :) Not there yet!

Answer (score 0):

```
getMtach [] _ = []
getMtach ((a, b, c):xs) key
    | (a == key) = (b, c) : getMtach xs key
    | otherwise = getMtach xs key

Main> getMtach [(1, "abc", 12.3), (2, "asg", 4.5), (1, "xyz", 123)] 1
[("abc",12.3),("xyz",123.0)]
*Main> 
*Main> getMtach [(1, "abc", 12.3), (2, "asg", 4.5), (1, "xyz", 123)] 2
[("asg",4.5)]
```